# Joining RDD leftOuterJoin - error: type mismatch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Trying to join two RDDs of different sizes with leftOuterJoin. Have managed this with other similar RDDs, but for some reason I'm getting this error now:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int, Double, Double, AnyVal)]
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, ?)]
```

with an arrow pointing to the object userScaleBack (that has the structure of the "found" error":

```
val userProdItemScale = itemAverages.leftOuterJoin(userScaleBack)
```

As you can see the object contains of tuples and 5tuples, and they have the respective counts 1650 and 80000. All of the values in the leftmost element are shared between the two object, so the ?-value should just be concatenated to all of the places in the larger object where leftOuterJoin matches. Contents of objects looks like this:

```
userScaleBack
(1053,451,2.7362637362637363,0.011609034023077685,2.2637362637362637)
(466,451,2.7362637362637363,0.052013404418021464,2.2637362637362637)

itemAverages
(1053,3.473684210526316)
(466,3.4390243902439024)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the type of `userScaleBack` to `RDD[(Int, ?)]`, i.e. an RDD of tuples with two elements. You can use `keyBy` to do this:

```
val userProdItemScale = itemAverages.leftOuterJoin(userScaleBack.keyBy(_._1))
```

Comment: Thanks, but then I loose the idea of userScaleBack. I want to avoid discarding all the other values. It's been possible to do this operation with similar objects of different sizes, so I don't think they need to have the same tuple size or count for it to work

Comment: The values won't be discarded. They will be kept as a 4-tuple in the second element. I don't think it works with different-sized objects... Could you show an example where it worked with objects of different sizes?

Comment: Yes, I will edit my question and add it to the bottom